# Trying to get property of non-object in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my controller

```
public function show($restaurant_id)
{
    $data = Restaurant::find($restaurant_id)->waitingtimes();
    echo $data->first()->value; exit;
```

I got `Trying to get property of non-object` though the `waitingtime` model is mapped to a database table that has the `value` column.

Could you help please? Also, could you tell me where can I read the documentation about the returning type of the function `find()` thanks

#### Edit 1

The data is not empty; I can see the database, and the `restaurant` table has the id 20 and the table waitingtimes has values that its `restaurant_20` is 20

Comment: The documentation for find can be found [here](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_find)

Comment: You need to use Route::bind() which will allow you to trap the instance of not getting a result from the route, and do i.e. `if(!$user) return App::abort(404);` to return a 404 error instead of the error you are getting...

Comment: @JustinE I need to print the $data variable now and later I will handle the user's error input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution myself, which is:

```
public function show($restaurant_id)
{
    $data = new Restaurant(array('id' => $restaurant_id));
    $data = $data->waitingtimes();
    echo $data->first()->value; exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually - what is better is to map the route to a model.

So in your Routes.php file:

```
Route::model('restaurant', 'Restaurant');

Route::get('/restaurant/{restaurant}', ['as' => 'restaurant.show', 'uses' => RestaurantController@show]);
```

Then in your controller file:

```
public function show(Restaurant $restaurant)
{
    echo $restaurant->waitingtimes()->first()->value;
}
```

You can read more about [Route Model Binding here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: why did you suppose that I didn't route the model to the route ? :) I already did and that has nothing to do with my problem. In other words, the problem appears though the map exists

Comment: You need to use Route::bind() which will allow you to trap the instance of not getting a result from the route, and do i.e. `if(!$user) return App::abort(404);` to return a 404 error instead of the error you are getting...

Comment: Also, @AnastasieLaurent You did not specify that in your question.

Comment: Also @AnastasieLaurent If you are using Route Model Binding, your code should be: `echo $restaurant_id->waitingtimes()->first()->value; exit;` as $restaurant_id will be an instance of your restaurant class.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent I assumed you are not using the Route Model binding because you are not using it in your controller correctly. Look at my controller show function. It is different to yours. You need to specify (Restaurant $restaurant). Then you dont ever need to "find" the Restaurant - Laravel gives it to you.

Comment: And if you are using relationships, they come already bound with the object returned from the Route::Model binding.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange that is correct, but for now, I would like to keep using my way and just print the value. could u help please?

Comment: @JustinE yes I am using relationship so could u tell me please how to print the data?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent `echo $restaurant_id->waitingtimes()->first()->value;` should be sufficient. If not, check your laravel.log in app/storage/logs and copy the backtrace to a pastebin...

Answer (score 0):

here is the source of find()
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L643

and here you have the docs

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_find

for your non-object error,

your $data is empty, you should check that before you use the $data collection

Comment: the data is not empty for sure, I can see it in my database. if you want, tell me any statement to test the data and print the output.